# How to Run Blue Prism Scheduled Jobs on Cloud VM based BOT server

Tags: blueprism

I am having architecture where my BOT server is on Cloud VM. To access that VM, I do RDP. I scheduled all the BP jobs on that BOT on VM. Now when I am connected to VM using RDP and keep the Blue Prism window in foreground, my BP jobs are running fine, means in Attended mode, they are fine. But if I minimize that BP window or if I dont do RDP to VM machine, I am getting error 'failed to navigate'. That means in unattended mode on my Cloud based VM BOT server, jobs are not running.

NOTE: My BP VM machine is always up and running also its not getting locked also, as I disabled windows screen lock (alt+ctrl+del).

In this scenario, will logon agent help or any other suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

Utilizing an environment relying on RDP is not supported or recommended by Blue Prism, as it causes issues with automated processes (as you describe). Please refer to page 4 of the **Blue Prism Data Sheet - Remote Access Tools** (available in the Documents tab of the Blue Prism client portal):

> The following tools have been deemed to be **specifically unsuitable** for providing remote access to Blue Prism environments:
>
> - **Remote Desktop Connection (RDP)**
>
>   The way that this Windows tool (and other tools that use the RDP protocol) handle session management is not compatible with Blue Prism:
>
>   - The underlying operating system is aware as a connection is
>       established which can, subject to the automation techniques being
>       applied, result in the executing automation being interupted.
>   - It requires the remote access credentials to be aligned with the
>       credentials used to authenticate the target system against the
>       network which presents a potential security risk.
>   - As a user authenticates any previously connected users are locked out.
>   - Each connection creates a separate desktop session.
>   - The connection is not maintained throughout a system reboot.

Comment: So what is the solution here. My App and DB servers are on Cloud. I connected these through my local laptop via RDP. Did my development and if I am running the processes on Cloud VM while I am connected through RDP, those are running fine. But when I am not making any connections through RDP to cloud VM, my processes are getting failed.

Comment: @Ashish - check out the data sheet I mentioned in my answer - it provides remote desktop technologies you can leverage that will not affect the automation.

Comment: Thanks! I On installing tools like VMware, BOMGAR etc.. Let me explain my issue again:
I actually dont want any type of monitoring of my BP App server or BP jobs. My only aim to run my BP jobs (scheduled on BP App server, residing on Cloud VM) in background without any user intervention or monitoring or without any need to keep the BP window in foreground/focused through RDP or any VM monitoring tool.
As I said even through RDP also, if I am not putting my BP screen in foreground or focused, BP jobs are getting failed.

Comment: @Ashish did you manage to find the solution? It would be really helpful if you please share the solution

Answer (score 0):

It does not matter whether the VM is in cloud or within your own infrastructure, they both have same issue. Blueprism needs "screen" to be able to interact with applications. VM of course does not have a physical screen, but there is still a virtual one (I don't mean the RDP one by this) as the virtualization layer provides virtual GPU and monitor.

Imagine a non-virtual pc left unlocked. This is the same. Even if you don't see it (you have to look for "console", some clouds provide access to it), it exists.

There are more possibilities how to solve it, two of them are:

1) use Blueprism Login Agent

- This will unlock the physical/virtual screen of the machine with given AD/Windows credentials, like a human user would before he starts working with the pc.
- Please search internet for more infor about it or look up videos on youtube, like this one:  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Eeeeu_iHjzk&list=PL4SEtvjUqihFh-iFvb_s0VAhPCX1tzg2A&index=43

  (I am not the author of this video nor affiliated with the author)

2) modify Windows registry setting to log in automatically

- More info:  https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/324737/how-to-turn-on-automatic-logon-in-windows

Answer (score -1):

I've encountered this problem before.

Try using the BluePrism's "Login Agent"'s "Login" process with the BOT's credentials.

If you continue to get this error, try using a "Dynamic" Spy mode for a particular attribute.

Good luck.

Comment: Thanks everyone! I dont see any use of Logon agent in my scenario. Why because, my App server on Cloud VM is always up and running, and as I said even screen lock is also disabled. My only aim to run my BP jobs (scheduled on BP App server, residing on Cloud VM) in background without any user intervention or monitoring or without any need to keep the BP window in forground/focused through RDP or any VM monitoring tool.

As I said even through RDP also, if I am not putting my BP screen in foreground or focused, BP jobs are getting failed. 

Pl assist